# I have problem with pre-flight request on react website when axios request post method it send optional request before

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, request

**I have problem on react when axios request post method it send optional request before i want to send post request only! how to handle this problem ??**

this is my function :

```
export async function onGetP(){
    let data= await axios.post(`${Link}/getP`, { "ApiKey": ApiKey , "Cust": ReactSession.get("Cust")  }).then(res => {
      const data = decrypt(res.data);
      const datajson = JSON.parse(data);
        return (datajson);
    });
    return data
}
```

Comment: are you talking about pre-flight request - [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#preflighted_requests_in_cors)

Comment: yes how to disable it ?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: the company i work on it don't want it because it not secure!!

Comment: as it is a cross origin request, a pre-flight request with the OPTIONS will be sent so that the server knows if its acceptable to proceed further with the POST ... not sure how its not secure tbh

Comment: me to i don't know how but they don't want it

Comment: you cannot disable the OPTIONS request. it's part of the security measures taken by the browser